# R: (*SKIP)(*FAIL) for multiple patterns

Tags: regex, r, boolean

Given `test <- c('met','meet','eel','elm')`, I need a single line of code that matches any 'e' that is not in 'me' or 'ee'. I wrote `(ee|me)(*SKIP)(*F)|e`, which does exclude 'met' and 'eel', but not 'meet'. Is this because `|` is exclusive or? At any rate, is there a solution that just returns 'elm'?

For the record, I know I can also do `(?<![me])e(?!e)`, but I would like to know what the solution is for `(*SKIP)(*F)` and why my line is wrong.

Comment: Not sure of a solution, but the regex is matching the second `"e"` of `"meet"` in isolation, with a length of 1, as per: `regexpr("(ee|me)(*SKIP)(*F)|e",test,perl=TRUE)`

Comment: I need to use this line in `gsub`, so I don't believe this is a solution.

Comment: I wasn't proposing a solution, simply giving some more information that `regexpr` provides for the regex you are using. The match is on the second "e" of "meet" alone, after "ee" and "me" are skipped.

Comment: It is because `me` is found first (because it is more on the left of the string than `ee` in the substring `mee`), so `ee` can't be found for the substring `mee`  because the two first letters are already consumed by the regex with the `me` subpattern. The solution is to replace `me` with `mee?` in your pattern. Keep in mind that a regex engine searches the string from the left to the right, character by character.

Comment: Other thing, don't forget that NFA regex engines (like the one used in R language) always choose the first branch that succeeds in an alternation (DFA regex engines choose the branch that matches the longest substring).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct solution with `(*SKIP)(*F)`:

```
(?:me+|ee+)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|e
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/jA8wX4/1), using the following test cases:

```
met
meet
eel
elm
degree
zookeeper
meee
```

Only `e` in `elm`, first `e` in `degree` and last `e` in `zookeeper` are matched.

Since `e` in `ee` is forbidden, any `e` in after `m` is forbidden, and any `e` in a substring of consecutive `e` is forbidden. This explains the sub-pattern `(?:me+|ee+)`.

While I am aware that this method is not extensible, it is at least logically correct.

### Analysis of other solutions

#### Solution 0

```
(ee|me)(*SKIP)(*F)|e
```

Let's use `meet` as an example:

```
meet        # (ee|me)(*SKIP)(*F)|e
^           # ^

meet        # (ee|me)(*SKIP)(*F)|e
  ^         #        ^

meet        # (ee|me)(*SKIP)(*F)|e
  ^         #               ^
            # Forbid backtracking to pattern to the left
            # Set index of bump along advance to current position

meet        # (ee|me)(*SKIP)(*F)|e
  ^         #                  ^
            # Pattern failed. No choice left. Bump along.
            # Note that backtracking to before (*SKIP) is forbidden,
            # so e in second branch is not tried

meet        # (ee|me)(*SKIP)(*F)|e
  ^         # ^
            # Can't match ee or me. Try the other branch

meet        # (ee|me)(*SKIP)(*F)|e
   ^        #                    ^
            # Found a match `e`
```

The problem is due to the fact that `me` consumes the first `e`, so `ee` fails to match, leaving the second `e` available for matching.

#### Solution 1

```
\w*(ee|me)\w*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|e
```

This will just skips all words with `ee` and `me`, which means it will fail to match anything in `degree` and `zookeeper`.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tL0bO5/1)

#### Solution 2

```
(?:ee|mee?)(*SKIP)(?!)|e
```

Similar problem as solution 0. When there are 3 `e` in a row, the first 2 `e` are matched by `mee?`, leaving the third `e` available for matching.

#### Solution 3

```
(?:^.*[me]e)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|e
```

This throws away the input up to the last `me` or `ee`, which means that any valid `e` before the last `me` or `ee` will not be matched, like first `e` in `degree`.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bF6cZ6/1)

Comment: I didn't know we were getting all fancy with something that doesn't even need backtracking verbs.

Comment: @hwnd: Yep, OP mentioned that in the question, though I'm just answering what OP wants to know about backtracking verb solution.

Answer (score 4):

You need a preceding/following boundary forcing the regex engine to not retry the substring.

```
gsub('\\w*[em]e\\w*(*SKIP)(?!)|e', '', test, perl=T)
```

Or as @CasimiretHippolyte pointed out — preceding with an optional "e" ...

```
gsub('(?:ee|mee?)(*SKIP)(?!)|e', '', test, perl=T)
```

**Updated** per comments ( Use a quantifier (*for other cases*) ):

```
gsub('[em]e+(*SKIP)(?!)|e', '', test, perl=T)
```

**Note:** I decided to use `(?!)` instead of `(*F)` which is also used to force a regex to fail.

```
(?!)    # equivalent to ( (*FAIL) or (*F) - both synonyms for (?!) ), 
        # causes matching failure, forcing backtracking to occur
```

Overall, the syntax can be written as `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`, `(*SKIP)(*F)` or `(*SKIP)(?!)`

Comment: You should explain that `(*FAIL)`, `(*F)`, `(?!)` or `^` *(<=not too bad isn't it)* are equivalent.

Comment: `meee` Your second regex matches the last `e`. `meeete` Your first regex fails to match the last `e`.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `\w*` in your first pattern to help the engine with more data, telling that `ee` or `me` can appear at the beginning, middle or end of a string.

You can use a regex like this:

```
\w*(ee|me)\w*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|e
```

R regex would be,

```
> test <- c('met','meet','eel','elm')
> gsub("\\w*(?:ee|me)\\w*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|e", "fi", perl=TRUE, test)
[1] "met"  "meet" "eel"  "film"
```

**OR**

```
> gsub('(?:^.*[me]e)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|e', 'fi', test, perl=T)
[1] "met"  "meet" "eel"  "film"
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hS1rN1/1)**

[image]

Comment: `temeeete` Your second regex fails to match the first `e`. `meeete` Your first regex fails to match the last `e`

Comment: @nhahtdh thanks to point that. Saw your solution, very clever