# How to replace a word unless it immediately follows another word

Tags: r, regex

How can I replace a word unless it immediately follows another word please. For example, for the vector `vec` below, how to replace the `the` in the third element with `of the`.

The rule for the example below is to: replace 'the' unless it comes immediately after 'of'

```
vec <- c("time of the day", "word of the day", "time the day")

# This also replaces the 'the' when following 'of'
gsub("the", "of the", vec)
# "time of of the day" "word of of the day" "time of the day"
```

The expected outcome is `c("time of the day", "word of the day", "time of the day")`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639562/r-skipfail-for-multiple-patterns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287204/ignore-part-of-a-string-when-splitting-using-regular-expression-in-r

Comment: `sub('(?<!of) the', ' of the', vec, perl = TRUE)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your strings always only contain a single space between words, you may use

```r
gsub("(?<!\\bof\\s)the\\b", "of the", vec, perl=TRUE)
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(vec, "(?<!\\bof\\s)the\\b", "of the")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4vGaWF/3). The `the` whole word is replaced with `of the` only if `the` is NOT preceded with a whole word `of` and one single whitespace after it immediately before `the`.

**However**, there are a lot of scenarios when users type more than one space between words.

Hence, **a more generic solution** is

```r
> gsub("\\bof the\\b(*SKIP)(?!)|\\bthe\\b", "of the", vec, perl=TRUE)
[1] "time of the day" "word of the day" "time of the day"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4vGaWF/1) and the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/WpDDS2).

*Details*:

- `\bof the\b` - matches `of the` as whole words
- `(*SKIP)(?!)` - skips the match and the regex engine goes on to search for the next match from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `\bthe\b` - matches `the` whole word in any other context.

If the whitespaces between `of` and `the` are not limitless, say 1 to 100, you can use a `stringr` based solution like

```r
library(stringr)
vec <- c("time of the day", "word of the day", "time the day")
str_replace_all(vec, "\\b(?<!\\bof\\s{1,100})the\\b", "of the")
## => [1] "time of the day" "word of the day" "time of the day"
```

See [this online R demo](https://ideone.com/QUwqwS). [ICU regex flavor](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) that is used in `stringr` regex fnctions allows the use of [limiting quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) in the lookbehind patterns.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4vGaWF/2) (used the Java 8 option online as it also supports contrained-width lookbehind patterns.). Details:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\bof\s{1,100})` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a whole word `of` followed with one to 100 whitespace chars immediately before the current location
- `the` - a `the` string
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: Thank you Wictor. I wasn't ever going to get close to that

Comment: @user2957945 Added a stringr solution that might be also fit the purpose.

Comment: @user2957945 I see people suggesting other solutions, and decided to add the simplest solution on top of the answer. I explained why it is not the best IMHO.